# Json file does not load after selecting from dropdown

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a fixture file which have both positive and negative amounts.

I have a dropdown which makes me select ALL,positive and negative amount.

when i select negative for example the table does not get refreshed with negative amounts.

[image]

This is the dropdown html
This is my code test:

```
cy.intercept('/api/amounts/***/*****', {fixture: 'amount.json'}).as('amount')
        cy.wait('@amount')
     
        cy.get('.dropdown-header-title').eq(3).click()
        cy.get('.dropdown-list-item').contains('Negative').then(option =>{
            option[0].click()
            cy.get('.dropdown-header-title').contains('Negative')
        })
```

The json file can be as below:

```
{
  amount: ['-200,000', '40000', '400', '-200']
}
```

For info i have added just dummy test data but the file is larger
thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use `readfile` instead of `fixture`

```
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/amount.json").then((profile) => {
  cy.intercept('/api/amounts/***/*****', { fixture: 'amount.json' }).as('amount')
  cy.wait('@amount')

  cy.get('.dropdown-header-title').eq(3).click()
  cy.get('.dropdown-list-item').contains('Negative').then(option => {
    option[0].click()
    cy.get('.dropdown-header-title').contains('Negative')
  })
})
```

Comment: where will profile be used? thanks

Comment: i have used readfile but the page is not getting refreshed when doing the select.Anything else i can try pls?

Comment: @ZombiePie If you want to refresh the web page after selection your can try `cy.reload()`

Comment: this dont work as it is reloading the page making it reset the filters

Comment: @ZombiePie Do wait after selecting value and than try `cy.get('body').then((body) => {
    (body.find('#yourselector') })`

Comment: cy.wait(5000)
            cy.get('body').then((body) => {
                body.find('.dropdown-header-title').eq(3).trigger('click')
                cy.get('.dropdown-list-item').contains('Negative').click()
                    .then(option => {
                        option[0].click()
                        cy.get('.dropdown-header-title').contains('Negative')
                    })
            })

 _ Its still not refreshing the data with correct info
@Krupal Vaghasiya
Tried to do the same with just a json file it worked well but with intercept it is not working at all.

Comment: Not able to change it manually also in cypress